# Hit an api after every x minutes anywhere in the app

Tags: react-native, expo

I am having an expo react native app and in this app after login the jwt expires every x minutes and to get a new jwt there is an api which requires the old jwt token. So I want to know to to implement this particular task after every x minutes everywhere in the app after a person login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `setInterval` js built-in function in order to doing something loop in interval time. `x` is the number of milisecond the task will re-run.

```
setInterval(function() {
      // Retrieve new token by old token 
}, x);
```

Comment: but in which file?

Comment: should be in which file you handle the authentication flow.

Comment: but it will not run across all app